# AzCopy on Linux: copying between mounted folders fails

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azcopy

I have previouusly asked this on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1138832/azcopy-on-linux-copying-between-mounted-folders-fails) but had no takers. Apologies if this is considered a duplicate.

I have an Azure File share mounted as /source and an SMB/CIFS share mounted as /dest on an Azure VM running Ubuntu 20.04. Between the Azure File Share and VM and the NAS is an S2S VPN tunnel. There are no Windows computers in the mix.

I have several thousand 120-130 MB raw binary files organized in folders and subfolders that I need to copy from the Az FS to the NAS, but the AzCopy job fails after a few thousand successfully copied files with the puzzling error message:

```
> 2023/07/24 08:56:02 ERR: [P#7-T#7336] DOWNLOADFAILED:
> https://redacted.file.core.windows.net/folder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/sourcefile?se=2023-09-01T14%3A21%3A12Z&sig=-REDACTED-&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&spr=https&srt=sco&ss=bfqt&st=2023-06-30T06%3A21%3A12Z&sv=2022-11-02
> : 000 : request size greater than pacer target. When Enqueuing chunk.
> X-Ms-Request-Id:
```

That's the entirety of the logged error, and it repeats for every single file that has status DOWNLOADFAILED. I have no idea what it means and I can't find any reference to this or a similar error message anywhere.

AzCopy is v10.19.0, and this is the command I run on the Ubuntu 20.04 Azure VM:

```
./azcopy cp "sourcefolder/?SAStoken" "destinationfolder/" --check-md5=NoCheck --recursive=true --check-length=true --overwrite=false --preserve-last-modified-time=true --cap-mbps=60
```

Does anyone have any idea what the error message is trying to tell me? There are lots of moving parts in the setup (VM, Az file share, S2S VPN, NAS), so I have a hard time figuring out even where to begin looking.

Please note that several thousand files were successfully copied before this error started showing up in the log, and if I rerun the job to copy skipped/failed files, all files generate this error message.

I have played around with the azcopy cp options in order to get as close to "just copy this file with minimal checking" as possible, but I'm still ending up in the same situation.

Comment: Did you used "azcopy job resume" command?

Comment: Yes. When using the resume command, the files with status DOWNLOADFAILED fails again with the same puzzling error message. I have attempted to resume the job several times with the same result.

Comment: `rsync` is an alternative method to copy files between your Azure VM and the NAS. Please try this.

Comment: Not really an option. Rsync is painfully slow at ~5 MB/s in this scenario. It's why I tried doing this copy job with azcopy instead. I have ~10 TB of files I need to pull down from the Azure fileshare.

What I want to know is what the error message means so I can fix it. It's close to meaningless the way it's presented to me.